# ModuleNotFoundError in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a form with a submit button that uploads 2 files, 
one python file(info.py) and a image file(eg "img1").

In views.py, I used

```
from media.info import
```

to import the files in info.py to use the methods etc.

When I refresh the upload form page, I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'media.info'.
```

It seems that the server realizes that I do not have the info.py file yet, and hence the error found in views.py.

is there any way to solve this? any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you will need to load the module dynamically, means at the time you create the file on click of submit. See __import__ function https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__

Answer (score 0):

is media.info installed in the settings.py in Django?
like:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   'yourapp',
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   'django.contrib.humanize',
]
```

Without add the app in the settings.py Django is not able to import the app desired

Comment: can you post a bit of your settings.py about installed apps?
have you try to replace the . with a _ ?
maybe this can create problems with the import

Answer (score -1):

Points to note

- First of all you are thinking it wrong, `from media import *` expecting python files or modules to import not files.
- If you want a directory to act as a python module add `__init__.py` inside the directory
- If you want to serve media files you don't need any extra view use this in your `urls.py` file.

  urlpatterns += patterns('', (r'^media/(?P.*)$',
                          'django.views.static.serve',
                          {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))

Comment: hi, I am already using                                                                                                            if settings.DEBUG:                                                                          urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
                                                                                                              urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT).

Comment: `media` is a django app or media directory ?/
if it is a media directory what you are doing is note correct, you will get file path from form